# How to I resolve GTM Trigger not firing as expected

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I would like to set a tag to only fire on my homepage so have set a trigger

url path equals /

When I preview or debug the tag it seems to be firing on all pages of my site, when I then review the firing triggers it tells me its fired because of a filer (_event equals gtm.js). I have no idea where this filter comes from or how its been implemented as it isnt in the trigger I set up. Any ideas how I remove this so the tag doesn't always fire?

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading the debugger. Your first screenshot here:
[image]

indicates that the the trigger did **not** fire, as is indicated by the top X.

For a trigger to fire, all conditions (filters) have to pass. If even one condition doesn't pass, the trigger won't fire. Well, there are also blockers, but we'll leave them out for now.

Comment: If that is the case, when in the debugger and in the output why does it sat my tag fired 1 time(s) and in the tag details it says firing status = succeeded? (Have added image of this in original thread)

Comment: I don't see your changes to the original post, but in the scenario that you've described, you're likely using multiple triggers for your tag. Make a better screenshot that would show the whole preview debugger that you're looking at. Small screenshots lack context.